# Why do i get this error message when trying to add a new framework using carthage?

Tags: swift, xcode, github, frameworks, carthage

I want to add a FrameWork to this app I'm working on. It converts latitude and longitude coordinates to UTM coordinates.

I added this to the cartfile:
github "peterringset/UTMConversion" ~> 1.1

But when i run this code in the terminal to clone the framework:
carthage update --platform iOS

I get this error message:

```
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git clone --bare --quiet https://github.com/peterringset/UTMConversion.git /Users/Fallet/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/UTMConversion) failed with exit code 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I've used other external frameworks like this, and it used to work just fine.. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs due to a change in username by the publisher of his GitHub account. If you notice the link to the repository is `https://github.com/wtw-software/UTMConversion` while the `Carthage` reference is `"peterringset/UTMConversion"`. I was able to solve it by changing the `Carthage` reference to `"wtw-software/UTMConversion"`. But then you will get this error if you are on Swift 3 or below and Xcode 8 or below.

> Task failed with exit code 65.....This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details

So I digged into the logs and found this:

> Check dependencies
>   “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
>   ** BUILD FAILED **

I googled around this error and it looks like the project is developed with Swift 4 and with Xcode 9.